# Flutter RefreshIndicator to refresh widget defined on separate file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following codes in my `HomePage.dart`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    size = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: CustomColors.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                brightness: Brightness.light,
                expandedHeight: size.getSizePx(320),
                floating: false,
                title: _searchWidget(),
                titleSpacing: 0.0,
                elevation: 0,
                pinned: true,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        CustomIcons.settings,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {}),
                ],
                flexibleSpace: Container(
                  child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    background: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: size.getSizePx(10),
                        horizontal: size.getSizePx(10),
                      ),
                      color: CustomColors.lightBlueBg,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.getSizePx(100)),
                        child: Text("TEST"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: size.getSizePx(10),
              horizontal: size.getSizePx(10),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: size.getSizePx(10)),
                NewItems(),             
                SizedBox(height: size.getSizePx(10)),
                PremiumItems(),
                SizedBox(height: size.getSizePx(10)),
                PopularItems(),
                SizedBox(height: size.getSizePx(40)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

`NewItems()`,`PremiumItems()`,`PopularItems()` are three widgets defined in three separate files. Basically these widgets are horizontally scrollable items for product showcase. All API and future calls are made on the respective files.

**Problem**

I want to use `RefreshIndicator` on `HomePage.dart`. So when pulled down, then homepage gets refreshed with updated contents. How do I update these three widgets with refreshindicator? It would have been easier if I would have put all codes of these three widgets in Homepage. Is it possible to do with my current set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a keys for each widget and have access to function inside `Statefull` widget here an example

```
final GlobalKey< PremiumItemsState> premiumItemsKey = GlobalKey();

Column(
children:[
...
PremiumItems(key:premiumItemsKey),
]
)


class PremiumItems extends StatefulWidget {
  const PremiumItems({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  PremiumItemsState createState() => PremiumItemsState();
}

class PremiumItemsState extends State<PremiumItems> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void update() {
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

by so you can have access to `update()` function inside `PremiumItemsState` class, and call `premiumItemsKey.currentState.update()` from home page